# AttributeError: 'Persona' object has no attribute 'Hablar'

Tags: python, clase

Tengo el siguiente error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

> AttributeError: 'Persona' object has no attribute 'Hablar'

Este es el código:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.edad =18  
        self.nombre ="jose"
        print ("se ha creado a",self.nombre,"de",self.edad,"años")     
        
def Hablar (self, palabras):print (self.nombre,': ',palabras)


jose=Persona()
jose.Hablar("hola,soy un gamer")
```

Comment: Primero: leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para que te familiarices con los lineamientos del sitio. Segundo: Indentar bien tu código ya que `Hablar` no está adentro de la clase.

Comment: Como dice  @HeytalePazguato Si indentas bien el código ya funciona correctamente. En python es importante  indentar bien el código.

Answer (score 3):

La indentación es relevante en Python:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.edad = 18
        self.nombre = "jose"
        print("se ha creado a", self.nombre, "de", self.edad, "años")


    def Hablar(self, palabras):
        print(self.nombre, ': ', palabras)
```

`Hablar` es un método de la clase `Persona`, por lo que debe estar indentando dentro de la clase.